# setting the shipping address of a quote doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, api

> I am trying to implement a magento 1.9 API for a mobile application
>   and I tried to implement saveShipping address for checkout process like below :

```
    function set_shipping_address($params){

    $this->check_customer_login();

    $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())->getStoreIds();

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($this->_customer_id);

    $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();        

    $customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($params['address_id']);

    $address->importCustomerAddress($customerAddress)->setSaveInAddressBook(0);       

    $address->implodeStreetAddress();
    $address->setCollectShippingRates('1');

    $quote->collectTotals()->save();


    return true;
 }
```

but I got the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getIsQtyDecimal() on a non-object in /home/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Abstract.php on line 193
```